# How to interact with DecisionTree.io API in React

Tags: api, reactjs

Can someone please help me connect to this API with GET and PUT examples?

I'm trying to interact with the API of www.decisiontree.io using React. Their api docs are [here.](https://decisiontree.io/api_docs) I was told I could interact with their API using a token generated in my account settings, but I don't know how to use it.

I'm a noob at this, but have spent hours examining endpoints via Chrome inspector network tab, and trying different "get" and "put" requests via Postman.

I'm gone through a couple of tutorials that include some data fetching using fetch() and axios, such as [this one from teamtreehouse.](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/data-fetching-in-react)

I generated a token using my name 
mikepeiman: `711KKulyQpcAkVbonKNagAG4LqhUs8tR0GCJj3c30IO77gJWP7d2u0g0T4Ro`

And from inspector:networks I got these:

x-csrf-token: `3b3yPcni9aK9L7FOhtDccCQqkbMK257jHLjiqKF`

x-xsrf-token: `eyJpdiI6IlNmekxGbGxYcDhya0k1bnMrM2FhdUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVyt6QjZzdHFKaWJFdXRHSGJcL1Rtdk15NXJrQWZHNDFMSytQeVdKcGNCbHIxc2hwZkV1R3pnVk9jXC9xZnpITVlTcFllOEJFZWQyS0tCajRDeGZuQVU3dz09IiwibWFjIjoiODk5ZWZjMWMwNTc3MmVkNTA5NzZhMmViMmNmMmExNzU2MTJhNzA1OTdkOWY3ZDljYjg5Y2M3ODk0NWM4OWQwZCJ9`

Here's what I attempted in adapting the tutorial code above to this API, inside my App component in app.js:

```
getGoal = (query) => {
  axios.get('https://https://decisiontree.io/api/decisions/27/name')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
      goals: response.data.goals.name
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
  });
}

postGoal = (query) => {
  axios.post(`https://https://decisiontree.io/api/decisions/27/add-goal/${query}/`)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
      addGoal: response.data.goals.name
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
  });
}

  render() { 
    console.log(this.state.goals);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-header">
          <div className="inner">
            <h1 className="main-title">GifSearch</h1>
            <SearchForm onSearch={this.getGoal}/>      
            <AddGoal onSearch={this.postGoal}/>
          </div>   
        </div>    
        <div className="main-content">
          <GifList data={ this.state.goals } />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Mike, the main issue here is that the documentation available with the decision tree api is not very clear as to how we must fire the api requests. I went through the api docs, created a free account, generated the token, but could not find a single sentence in the docs on how to use the token. If you have a paid account, I suggest you drop a mail to support on how to use the api. Once you have that figured out, integrating it with React, or any other library for that matter should be easy.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. I thought maybe it was just because I'm a noob at this and there was something obvious I missed. No, I'm not a paid member, just a free member and created a token like you. I met the founder at a Hackernest event, I'll send him an email to ask.

Comment: Sure .. and please update the post with your findings if you do get a reply

Comment: He never responded to the email, but when I saw him at a Meetup last night and asked, he suggested simply to use the app and watch the activity in network tab to identify how to use the endpoints.

Comment: Well that doesn't seem very promising. Give it a try though